# Recalculate extent for versioned featureclass

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, extents, feature-class

I try to recalculate extent for FC (versioned). I deleted some objects with null geometry, or with wrong location and reconcile every versions. But I still cannot recalculete extent to new proper values. Values are still the same - wrong. Do anybody know where could be a problem?

When I export FC (sde.default) to fgbd, extent is correct.

Comment: What level license do you have and what tool did you use?

Comment: License is advanced and i try do use arcpy function recalculatefeatureclassextent. There no problem to run this tool, but problem is to really recalculate extent after deleting wrong fetures in every version..I checked every version and features was deleted.